# Migrating Business Objects IES 10901

Tags: business-objects

I moved reports from BOBJ 4.2 to BOBJ 4.3 on a new machine and received the following error:

> (CS) "DBDriver failed to load : D:\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP
> BusinessObjects Enterprise XI
> 4.0\dataAccess\connectionServer\drivers\lib64\dbd_oci.dll (The specified module could not be found. )" . For information about this
> error, please refer to SAP Knowledge Base Article 2054721 on the SAP
> Support Portal. (IES 10901)

The DLL does exist at that location. We installed the Oracle drivers. Is there a step I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is system environment variables for ORACLE_HOME